Flutter app shows different UI on Android and iOS. What could be causing this discrepancy and how can I ensure consistency?
enter image description here in this image you can see there is UI difference in the Tap like this there are several other also, please let me know what can be the problem
i wanted to know how do i debug this from where to start if anyone has faced the same issue

"where to start" Post a [mre], without seeing your code we can only guess.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

please check the image once i am new to flutter, i will give you the code but at first glance this is the issue

do not "give a glance" in question, always post specific problem (part 1, done) and sample code, which causes that problem (part 2, lack of). without code every answer will be a guess
